# classify unlabeled 20ng dataset

Tags: java, weka, data-mining

I have an unlabeled 20 newsgroup dataset without class labels. It's a multiclass text dataset. But I don't know class labels; I want to use weka API to classify it. But weka uses class labels to classify datasets. The link is [20ng dataset](http://csmining.org/index.php/id-20-newsgroups.html)

Comment: I did use cluto gcluster tool on text dataset namely provided by kaypis lab k1a; it creates clusters ranging from 0-9 and assigns different attributes to each cluster. What I am wondering is, whether to assigns as 0-9 digits to these different groups of attributes and then classify them using weka api. As my primary concern is using weka or there is any alternative.Either I provide string class labels or digits class labels as provided by clustering tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "lingo clustering algorithm" from carrot2 to generate labels from raw data.

https://project.carrot2.org/algorithms.html